# dojo.io.iframe.send file upload sends GET request in IE8

Tags: file-upload, internet-explorer-8, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I'm doing an xhr file upload using dojo.io.iframe.send and it works fine in all browsers except IE 8. IE8 sends a GET request instead of a multipart POST. This is my code:

```
dojo.io.iframe.send({
            form: this.logoForm.domNode,
            handleAs: "json",
            method: "POST",
            url: '/backend/design/uploadLogo',
            load: dojo.hitch(this, function(response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    errorFunc(response);
                } else {
                    this.submitStatusLogo.innerHTML = "Your logo has been successfully uploaded.";
                    this.logoButton.hideIndicator();
                    dojo.addClass(this.submitStatusLogo, "success");
                    if (response.logoPath) {
                        this.productLogo.innerHTML = '<img src="'+response.logoPath+'" alt="" />';
                    }
                }
            }),
            error: errorFunc
        });
```

And this.logoForm.domNode is:

```
<form dojoAttachPoint="logoForm" dojoType="dijit.form.Form" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="designLayoutForm">
    <div class="uploadedImage" dojoAttachPoint="productLogo"></div>
    <h2>Logo
        <span dojoType="sc2.common.TinyHelp" title="Logo">
            Upload a product logo that will be shown in the top left of the demo page.<br />
            If the logo is higher than 80 pixels, it will be resized to a height of 80px. <br />
            <br />
            <i>Supported file types are: png, jpg, gif, bmp.</i>
        </span>
    </h2>
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" dojoAttachPoint="logoForm_product" name="product" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" dojoAttachPoint="logoForm_XSessionVerify" name="X-Session-Verify" value="" />
        <input type="file" name="file" dojoAttachPoint="logoInput" />
    </p>
    <p dojoAttachPoint="submitStatusLogo" class="submitStatus"></p>
    <p>
        <input dojoType="sc2.form.IndicatorButton" dojoAttachPoint="logoButton" label="Upload">
    </p>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay I solved it, adding method="POST" to the form element did the trick. Apparently specifying method: "POST" in the send parameters was not sufficient for IE8. Thanks for your time anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I solved it, adding method="POST" to the form element did the trick. Apparently specifying method: "POST" in the send parameters was not sufficient for IE8. Thanks for your time anyway